How to show a custom icon in Delphi's TTaskDialog?
In a Delphi 12.1 VCL Application in Windows 11, I am trying to set up a TTaskDialog at design-time:
object TaskDialog2: TTaskDialog
  Buttons = <>
  Caption = 'Choose an Action'
  RadioButtons = <
    item
      Caption = 'Create a shortcut to this folder'
    end
    item
      Caption = 'Copy the folder and all its contents'
    end>
  Text = 'How do you want to insert the Folder?'
  Left = 676
  Top = 396
end

But there is no question mark choice for the MainIcon property.
I can load my own question mark ICO in CustomMainIcon at design-time. But how to show that CustomMainIcon?
The loaded CustomMainIcon is neither shown at design-time (with 'Test Dialog') nor at run-time (with TaskDialog2.Execute).

This is mentioned in the unofficial TTaskDialog documentation.

(In any case, using question-mark icons for question dialogs is not recommended. Microsoft deprecated these icons years ago.)

@AndreasRejbrand it is also in the official documentation, too

@RemyLebeau: Great! (It wasn't back then.)

Per Delphi's documentation:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomTaskDialog.CustomMainIcon

Indicates the custom main icon, if any, for the Task Dialog.
CustomMainIcon points to the custom main icon for this Task Dialog, if tfUseHiconMain is set in Flags.

The tfUseHiconMain flag is disabled by default.  Your setup needs to enable it.

Checking the tfUseHiconMain flag in TTaskDialog.Flags at design-time shows the CustomMainIcon both at design-time and at run-time.
This is the result when using a 32x32 pixel CustomMainIcon:

And this is the result when using a 64x64 pixel CustomMainIcon:

And this is the result when using a 128x128 pixel CustomMainIcon:

Note how bigger ICO files become pixelated, although all ICO files were created from Axialis Icon Generator (SVG sources).
